# Как игнорировать размер окна браузера?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Когда изменяется размер окна браузера, у меня съезжают объекты.
Можно сделать так, чтобы сайт не обращал внимание на изменение окна браузера.

Вот код:

```css
body {
  background-color: #151515;
}
p[id="output_text"] {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h[type="x1"] {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 4%;
  left: 40%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h[type="x2"] {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 4%;
  left: 60%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h[type="z1"] {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 19%;
  left: 40%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h[type="z2"] {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 19%;
  left: 60%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[name="nazad"] {
  background-color: #151515;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36);
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 105px;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;

  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  left: 55%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[name="nazad"]:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.29);
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  bottom: -5px;
  opacity: 0;

  top: 35%;
  left: 55%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[name="nazad"]:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.29);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #f04242;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  margin-right: -50%;
  top: 35%;
  left: 55%;
}

input[name="nazad"]:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* НАЧАЛО  кнопки "Готово" */
input[value="Готово"] {
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fafafa;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36);
  font-size: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 34.2%;
  left: 45%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 8px 25px;
  margin: 6px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

input[value="Готово"]:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  bottom: -5px;
  opacity: 0;

  top: 34.2%;
  left: 45%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[value="Готово"]:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #f04242;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1);
  margin-right: -50%;
  top: 34.2%;
  left: 45%;
}

input[value="Готово"]:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* КОНЕЦ  кнопки "Готово" */
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36);
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
}

input[type="text"]:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

/*——————————————————————*/
input[type="text1"] {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36);
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 40%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="text1"]:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
}

input[type="text1"]:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* ————————————————————————*/
input[type="text2"] {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36);
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 60%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="text2"]:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
}

input[type="text2"]:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

p[type="ygol1"] {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 6;
}

p[type="ygol2"] {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 53%;
  left: 66%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 7;
}

input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36);
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
}

input[type="text"]:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

/*——————————————————————*/
input[type="text3"] {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36);
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 40%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="text3"]:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
}

input[type="text3"]:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* ————————————————————————*/
input[type="text4"] {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36);
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 60%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="text4"]:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
}

input[type="text4"]:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

div[class="kvadrat"] {
  width: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #af0d0d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55.9%;
  left: 64%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
div[class="kvadrat1"] {
  width: 400px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #af0d0d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Расстояние</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
//ТУТ БЫЛ СКРИПТ
    </script>
    <div class="field">
        <input name="nazad" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'" value="Назад">
    </div>
    <div class="ygol1"></div>
    <div class="ygol2"></div>

    <div class="kvadrat"></div> 
    <div class="kvadrat1"></div></div>

    <div>
        <h type="x1">X1</h>
        <h type="x2">X2</h>
        <h type="z1">Z1</h>
        <h type="z2">Z2</h>
        <form name="input_form" action="javascript:validate();">
            <input type="text1" name="aterm1" size="5" required>
            <input type="text2" name="aterm2" size="5" required>
            <input type="text3" name="aterm3" size="5" required>
            <input type="text4" name="aterm4" size="5" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Готово">
        </form>

        <p type="ygol1" id="1"></p>
        <p type="ygol2" id="2"></p>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите код текстом

Comment: Какой-то бред чел.  Это даже чинить нельзя, тут все удалять и переверстывать.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле больно смотреть на верстку подобного рода, для начала скажу вам то что все стили связанные с расположением и размером блоков указаны в %, что крайне не правильно, исправьте этот момент и все отлично заработает